# Can I say: "This server is healthy." knowing that "server" is a material thing?

Tags: adjectives, expressions, dictionaries

I was wondering, is it proper to say: "This server is healthy." knowing that "server" (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/server) is a material thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean a computer serving information, not a waitress serving food.
Yes, it's a common metaphor.

Comment: It would be grammatically correct even if you were talking about a waitress.

Comment: True, but it might not be proper...

Comment: Yes, referring to a person as "this" is probably rude in most cases.